# Asp.net identity confirmation mails going to spam

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net identity for registering users, but confirmation mails going to spam instead of inbox:
[image]

Other types of messages going to inbox(html also). Just confirmation messages going to spam why? How to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change body/subject of message. Probably, similar messages were identified as spam before.
I understand, that you use "standard" message, but no way to influence on Google spam filter